# JavaFX2: How to retrieve Task in Service's onFailed event?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX Service and try to handle Task failure. For that I would like a reference to Task instance in handle method of OnFailed handler.
In debug I can see that the WorkerStateEvent source holds a task reference, but I cannot find a way to get to it other than reflection which I would like to avoid.

Am I missing something in here?

Comment: From looking at the JavaFX2.2 source, you should be able to say `Worker w = evt.getSource()`.

Comment: This is an excellent way to get a Service - both getSource and getTarget return the instance of a Service. But Service still hides the Task deep inside.

Comment: Hmmm.. This is somewhat confusing, as both a `Task` and a `Service` is a `Worker`... It seems that if you listen to the service's state, you'll have the service as source, if you listen to the task's state, you will have the task as source.

Comment: This perhaps could work, but I want to keep Task implementations as clean as possible - I believe that handling (logging) failure should be done in generic Service, not in Task. But perhaps I am overengineering here. If possible, post the above comment as an Answer as it may be satisfactory to most readers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a subclass of a Service with Class property (this is exactly what I needed, for logging purposes).

It does its job, but I'm not marking it as a proper solution because I don't like it. Perhaps someone has a better idea.